# Page rendering issue in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, cross-browser

I have a strange problem with Firefox 26.0 browser. I could see unaligned text for a second, before browser rendering the dynamic web page. my webpage works good in chrome and IE.

Initially it shows the incomplete UI, once it gets the service response, it shows unaligned text for a moment and immediately it loads the page properly. It gives some blinking effect.
Anyone have faced the similar issue?

Comment: I am using Firefox for browsing and development but I haven't seen this issue. Do you have Firebug installed? There is a bug when activating the script panel in Firebug that causes Firefox to be really sluggish.

Comment: No. I have not installed the FireBug. I am using tables for layout. Will it be a issue?

Comment: Using tables can make the page render a bit slower. Do you have a link of the page for us to take a look?

Comment: No. Its an internal site. I could not share the URL.

Comment: Are you adding classes using scripts (JavaScript/jQuery)? If these classes are not initially present then their effects will not be visible until the scripts have executed and added them to the appropriate elements. This may well explain the flash. Table layout has been deprecated for at least a decade now, if possible I'd strongly suggest you use CSS for your layout instead.

Comment: Alternatively, are you conditionally loading any stylesheets using something like yepnope or Modernizr?

Comment: I am not adding any classes using scripts and I am not using yepnope or modernizr. I have added Jquery functions in JS file which will get the data from REST service and populating the HTML page controls using java script. Dynamically creating tables in some part of the page. Why this prb happens only with Firefox rendering engine? Its process flow is different from other browsers?

Comment: Please can you give us any code you can to show the markup structure and what is dynamically being added to the page? Examples of the dynamically generated HTML would help. CSS for the page will also be necessary.

Comment: (Feel free to use fake/lorem ipsum data if it is a sensitive project, we simply need to see the HTML with *representative* content in terms of size/length, and the CSS used to style it)

Comment: @pwdst. Thanks for your effort. Sorry I am not even getting permission to even share code with fake data. One thing I could understand from debugging the code is, by default, before loading the page, (jquery-1.7.1.js) JQuery.ready() is called once. After loading the page, JQuery.ready() is called again. Till JS code binds the data in UI, there is no issue in my page. After binding, it invokes the JQuery.ready() function, during that time, this blink happens.

Comment: I just tried to debug the complete flow using firefox debugger. From top to end in my HTML and JS code, I am not getting that issue. Once control enters into the Jquery=1.7.1.js file at the end of loading process. I am getting this issue in firefox.

Comment: Can you produce a completely fake page or stripped down page that you could share and still replicates the issue? With the data available to us we could be guessing all year. Some guesses based on what you have said so far (and these can only be guesses)- 1. make sure have a single HTML document and have not nested one HTML document within the other (except in an iFrame) 2. make sure you are only including a single copy of jQuery, preferrably towards or at the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag - document ready (or the DOMContentLoaded event) shouldn't behave as you describe

Comment: Is this still an issue? Have you checked with regard to nested HTML documents and multiple copies of jQuery as per the last comment? Are you able to re-produce the issue in a test document so we can advise you? If you solved the issue, please answer your own question with details of how in case it will be useful to other developers in future.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the firebug and disable all debugger from browser.